# How to use the Vim global command on matches and on lines?

Tags: vim

I was wondering if it was possible to run a command on the search match and not on the line.

For instance, with this file:

```
asdf - asdf
hjkl - hjkl
```

If I run `:g/-/normal D` it will delete the content of all lines, but I'd rather delete the content from the match to the end of the line.

Is that possible ? I don't need to have several matches per line only that the command starts at the correct position.

This is only an example, I could use substitute in that particular example, but this not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/-.*//
```

are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse the match in your command so you will have to move to that match explicitely:

```
:g/-/normal f-D
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
:%norm t-D

t- .......... until before -
D ........... delete till end of line
```